Creating a GrapesJS editor with dynamic height to adjust for content size
I've been looking to create an editor using GrapesJS with a dynamic height that adjusts according to the content size. My goal is to have the editor expand its height as needed when content is inserted, causing the page to grow in height rather than displaying a scroll bar. Is it possible to achieve this with GrapesJS?
Thank you for your help!

I have the same question
